# "The name 'prevfundedList' does not exist in the current contex"

Tags: c#

I am unable to fix this issue and can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.
This is the else part to my code.

```
else {
      string prevFundedList = firstFundList;

      foreach (object[] item in tempRsList)
      {
           if(prevfundedList != fundedList && item[12].ToString() == "PinYear")
           {
                oExcelApp.Cells[rowNum, 1] = "SFY " + year.ToString() + " Planning List - Bypass Systems";
                oExcelApp.Cells[rowNum, 1].Font.Bold = true;
                rowNum = rowNum + 1;
           }
           prevFundedList = item[12].ToString();
      }
} // end of else
```

Error says

> "The name 'prevfundedList' does not exist in the current contex"

Comment: C# is case-sensitive, `prevFundedList` is not the same as. `prevfundedList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names in c# are case-sensitive.
You're declaration is `prevFundedList` but you use it in the if statement as `prevfundedList`.

Comment: OMG! I cannot believe I missed that. Such a rookie error. Thanks so much.